# Returning bool value react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have two actions one that will close my menu (would be false) and one that will open the menu (would be true) in my reducer I set the initial value to true

```
import { OPENED_MENU,CLOSED_MENU } from './types';

export const OpenMenu = status => ({
    type:OPENED_MENU,
    status
});
export const CloseMenu = status => ({
    type:CLOSED_MENU,
    status
});
```

reducer:

```
import { OPENED_MENU, CLOSED_MENU } from '../../actions/menu/types';

const initialState = {
    status: true,
};

const CheckingStatus = ( state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case OPENED_MENU:
            return{

            }
        case CLOSED_MENU:
            return{

            }
        default:
        return state;
    }
}

export default CheckingStatus;
```

I would like to know how I return in my action a false or true boolean value.

or how it could improve my logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
import {TOGGLE_MENU } from '../../actions/menu/types';

const initialState = {
    menuStatus: true,
};

const CheckingStatus = ( state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case TOGGLE_MENU:
            return{
              ...state,
              menuStatus: !state.menuStatus
            }

        default:
        return state;
    }
}

export default CheckingStatus;
```

Comment: so I just need to do an action with this type

Answer (score -1):

Why won't you toggle the menu value, you just create one action and use it to open and close.

On the reducer you toggle the prevState

Comment: could you make an example?

Comment: on the action you don't need to send any data.